# Error when compiling Prolog in SICStus using SPIDER IDE

Tags: sicstus-prolog

I have just installed SICStus Prolog and the SPIDER IDE plugin for Eclipse.
SPIDER was installed using the Update Site, and I set the SICStus installation path in the preferences and verified it.
Then I created a new workspace and a Prolog Project that contains only the following file `test.pl`:

```
test :- write('Hello World!'), nl.
```

When I compile (menu: SICStus > Compile Prolog Code), I get the following message in the "Toplevel" window:

```
Restarting Prolog

Unknown option '--spider'.

Usage: /Users/alexraasch/sicstus/bin/sicstus [options] [-- args ...]

Options:


    -f         Fast start. Do not read initialization files.

    -i         Force interactive mode.

    -m         Use maximally compatible memory manager bottom layer.

    -r <file>  Restore <file> after booting.

    -l <file>  Ensure that <file> (containing Prolog code)

               is loaded on startup.

    --goal <goal>  Execute <goal> after loading any files.

    -Xrs       Reduced use of OS-signals (see release notes)

    --help     Show this message and exit.



    -- ...     Pass the rest of the arguments as prolog_flag(argv,X).

    -a ...     Legacy name for --.



Report bugs using http://www.sics.se/sicstus/bugreport/bugreport.html


Process ended with exit value 1
```

My version numbers are:

- macOS 10.12.5
- Java SE 1.8.0_65
- Eclipse 4.6.0
- SICStus 4.0.8
- SPIDER 0.0.64

The SICStus installation was a pre-built installation.

I have never worked with SICStus, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 4.0.8 sounds very old. The current version is 4.3.5. [The doc](https://sicstus.sics.se/spider/releases.html#current) mentions 4.1.3 as the oldest working version.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That version of SICStus Prolog is too old to work with SPIDER.

You can download an evaluation version of the latest SICStus Prolog from the [SICStus Prolog site](https://sicstus.sics.se/). You can install it without uninstalling any version you already have.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll try that tomorrow in the office.